# select first_name,length(trim(FIRST_NAME)) as lengthOfName_without_space from employees;

Tags: sql

i have first name as 'jose manuel' in my database- its total character length is 11 (combining space)
when i run the above query it is showing me output as 11.
but i need output without space i mean after trimming space ie., 10.
how do i do that in sql.

Comment: Replace spaces with empty string. The exact function depends on the database you are using. Please tell us which database you are using.

Comment: my sql workbench

Comment: "trim" in this context means "remove from the beginning and end", not "remove from anywhere in the string"

Comment: MySQL Workbench is the tool you use to connect to the database server. Presumably you are using MySQL as the server as well. Please run `select version();` to verify.

Comment: yes mysql       am using

Comment: the version is '8.0.29'

Comment: Use `REPLACE()`. For example: `select replace('jose manuel', ' ', '')` -- Result `josemanuel`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34718fa0d4ccdae9a7b5970d9293c3a6

Comment: actually i need the length of the particular name after removing the space in between.'

Comment: Then apply `LENGTH()` to it. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f7f689809e868ad6d6b52ff1afe2c15

Comment: i tried using the same but its calculating the space in between the name as well.

Comment: Please reproduce the case un https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking through the comments, and The Impaler is correct.
In this circumstance, using Replace would help you a lot.

I've included testing data into a temporary table.
You can just use the select part without the stuff above that, just change the from part.

```
Declare @TestData TABLE
(
    FIRST_NAME      varchar(24)
);

INSERT INTO @TestData (FIRST_NAME) select 'jose manuel'
INSERT INTO @TestData (FIRST_NAME) select 'bob chris'
INSERT INTO @TestData (FIRST_NAME) select 'steven'

select t1.FIRST_NAME,
len(t1.FIRST_NAME) as 'Original_Length',
len( replace(t1.FIRST_NAME, ' ', '') ) as 'New_Length'
from @TestData as t1
```

The result of this will give you:

| FIRST_NAME | Original_length | New_length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jose manuel | 11 | 10 |
| bob chris | 9 | 8 |
| steven | 6 | 6 |